# What is the word that includes "Chiefs" and "Sergeants-Major" together?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, military

Is there a word or two that can combine Chief Master Sergeant/Petty Officer and Sergeants-Major? I want it in a sentence that involves both sets of ranks like: "'*The Chiefs and Sergeants-Major*' will come." or something like that.

The closest I have gotten are: **Senior NCOs** and **E-9s** but they sound very ambiguous or awkward sounding.

Comment: Senior NCOs seems apt to me. E-9s would be better, but very few people are likely to know that term or the military org chart in general.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that can ONLY mean them or simply comfortably includes them?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Word that means only them.

Comment: @DanBron Problem with that is that "Senior NCO" includes a few ranks below them which is not what I want it to mean.

Comment: Highest-ranking NCOs? Most senior NCOs?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I recomend the word `and`.

Comment: As with many single word requests, the word may exist, and you may add to your vocabulary, but you may get a word you cannot use because no one will understand it.  I understand "The Chiefs and Sergeants-Major" but will probably not understand the SINGLE word that includes them and no one else.

Comment: If this is for a story, invent a word, describe it, then use it.  Senco-9’s...  “yeah, all the Senco-9’s ’ll be there.”

Comment: @Jim Alright, that might work.